# How to get a frequency table from the count function under a certain condition?

Tags: r, count

For example this table shows that 28 values are missing for ethnicity and salary. 112 are missing for age and salary etc.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: `sapply(my_tibble[is.na(my_tibble$salary), ],  function(x) sum(is.na(x) ) )`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(is.na(salary)) %>% 
  is.na %>% 
  colSums
# ethnicity       age        ur   edlevel   mstatus  profstat    income    salary 
#         0         1         0         1         0         4         5         5
```

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text ='  ethnicity   age    ur edlevel mstatus profstat income salary
 1         1     3     1       1       3       NA     NA   NA  
 2         1     4     1       1       2       NA      0   27.1
 3         6     4     1       1       1       NA      0   41.0
 4         6    NA     1      NA       2        2     NA   NA  
 5         6     4     1       1       1        4      4  484. 
 6         6     3     1       1       1       NA     NA   NA  
 7         6     2     1       1       1       NA     NA   NA  
 8         6     4     1       1       1       NA      4  570. 
 9         6     3     1       1       3       NA     NA   NA  
10         3     1     1       2       3        4     12 2404. ', header = T)
```

Comment: Similar : `colSums(is.na(df$salary) & is.na(df))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(is.na(salary)) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```